# Adding buttons plus / minus to the cart and update on AJAX request

Tags: jquery, ajax, opencart-3

Added to the basket buttons plus / minus to change the amount of product in the basket. But I cannot understand how to connect Ajax correctly for updates.

I tried different values in Ajax data.

```
<button  type="button" class="minus">-</button>
<input type="text" name="quantity[{{ product.cart_id }}]" value="{{ product.quantity }}" size="1" class="form-control cart-q" id="score"/>
<script>
$('.minus').click(function () {
     var $input = $(this).parent().find('#score');
 ﻿    var count = parseInt($input.val()) - 1;
     count = count < 1 ? 1 : count;
     $input.val(count);
     $input.change();
     return false;
     setTimeout(function () {
      $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'index.php?route=checkout/cart/edit',
        data: 'key=' + $input.name() + '&quantity=' + $input.val(),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function () {
          $﻿('#cart > ul').load('index.php?route=common/cart/info ul li');
        }
      });
    }, 100);﻿﻿﻿
</script>
```

Input value changed but cart value not update, and no error in console.
Please help.

Comment: i'd call the ajax as callback of the minus function. Why are you using a timeout for that?

Answer (score 0):

Cart is not updating because you have a return statement before the ajax call.

removed return statement also there is no need of timeout.

```
$('.minus').click(function () {
     var $input = $(this).parent().find('#score');
     var count = parseInt($input.val()) - 1;
     count = count < 1 ? 1 : count;
     $input.val(count);
     $input.change();
      $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'index.php?route=checkout/cart/edit',
        data: 'key=' + $input.name() + '&quantity=' + $input.val(),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function () {
          $('#cart > ul').load('index.php?route=common/cart/info ul li');
        }
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Send the data in JSON format. Also, remove `return` before AJAX call

```
<script>
  $('.minus').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $input = $(this).parent().find('#score');
        var count = parseInt($input.val()) - 1;
        count = count < 1 ? 1 : count;
        $input.val(count);
        $input.change();
        setTimeout(function() {
          $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'index.php?route=checkout/cart/edit',
            data: {
              key: $input.name(),
              quantity: $input.val()
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function() {
              $('#cart > ul').load('index.php?route=common/cart/info ul li');
            }
          });
        }, 100);
</script>
```